Ways of creating a struct directly?
I know I can create a Polars struct "scalar" indirectly using dictionaries as elements when building a series. But is there any way in which I can directly create a Polars struct scalar directly? (Not in a series, or a dataframe.)
For reasons I am not clear on, people think this question might be similar to Ways of creating a `pyarrow.StructScalar` directly?.
It is not, because:

while Polars uses Arrow under the hood, it only provides functionality for translating Arrow arrays into Polars Series, and Arrow tables into Polars DataFrames --- there is no functionality for converting Arrow scalars into Polars scalars
because Polars uses Arrow under the hood, we can forget about the fact that Polars uses Arrow when attempting to answer the question: "how can we create a Polars scalar?"
finally, note that while the other question had a relatively quick solution, this one does not!


There is the pl.struct expression e.g. foo = pl.struct(x=1, y=pl.lit('two')) but not sure if that's what you're asking for.

@jqurious Hmm. I think that might be good enough. Hopefully I can use a list of such expressions to create a Series. Let me see.

@jqurious I seem to be getting stuck on the simplest things. Am I right in understanding that there's no way to build a series from a list of expressions? e.g.
pl.Series([pl.struct(hello=4, world="zero"), pl.struct(hello=0, world="2024 Jan")], dtype=pl.Struct({"hello": pl.Int16(), "world": pl.String()})).
I guess because expressions are meant to create series within the context of a dataframe?

You are right - that's just not how expressions are designed to be used. In that case you would just use normally just use dict(hello=0, world="2024 Jan") as you mentioned.

Technically, you can do things like: pl.select(pl.concat([pl.struct(hello=4, world=pl.lit("zero")), pl.struct(hello=0, world=pl.lit("2024 Jan"))]))

This question is similar to: Ways of creating a `pyarrow.StructScalar` directly?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@folengateis No, it is extremely different. Note how that question has an answer, while this question has no answer yet. While polars uses arrow under the hood, it only lets you transform arrow arrays into polars Series, and arrow tables into polars DataFrames.

@folengateis Not a good use of my time, but I updated this question to explain how it is different from the other question.

What do you mean by a polars struct scalar directly? AFAIK, polars datatypes exist only within a series or dataframe. If you get any specific item of a polars dataframe / series, it'll be a "standard" python type. Especially, a struct outside of a series or dataframe is just a dictionary.

AFAIK, this is not possible. Polars datatypes are used to type contents of polars dataframes and series. You cannot have data of a polars dtype outside of a datafame and series. Especially, the contents of a struct column would be a regular dictionary.
Consider the following example. We create a polars dataframe with a single struct column "my_structs" (with fields "int_field" and "float_field") and a single row of data.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "my_structs": {"int": 1, "float": 1.0}
})

Now, if we select the struct column and take the single item it stores, the result will be a regular python dictionary.
df.get_column("my_structs").item()

{'int_field': 1, 'float_field': 1.0}

